# How to redirect default permalink with htaccess on wordpress?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to redirect default permalink to new domain with `/%postname%/` permalink by `.htaccess?` I already try all case with **Redirect** and **RedirectMatch** but didn't work.

```
Redirect 301 /?p=123 http://newdomain.com/new-post

Redirect 301 http://olddomain.com/?p=123 http://newdomain.com/new-post

RedirectMatch 301 /?p=123 http://newdomain.com/new-post

RedirectMatch 301 http://olddomain.com/?p=123 http://newdomain.com/new-post
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Yes, I have try but it didn't match its change the domain only not the post... The logic :olddomain:/?p=123 become :newdomain:/?p=123 BUT should become :newdomain:/new-post...

Comment: its mean all of post in olddomain become newdomain/new-post... i want :olddomain:/?p=123 become :newdomain:/new-post else :olddomain:/?p=124 become :newdomain:/new-post2